# Drivers not compatible (webcam, sound) on dragonfly g4 with unbuntu

Tags: ubuntu, audio, driver, compatibility, webcam

I have just received the new HP dragonfly g4. I installed the latest LTS version of ubuntu (22). Unfortunately, when I started using it, I noticed two problems: the speakers don't work and neither does the webcam. They're probably not recognized by the computer. On the other hand, wired sound works just fine.

From what I've read on Internet, hp mainly develops drivers for Windows and not for Linux... https://www.xda-developers.com/can-hp-elite-dragonfly-g3-run-linux/

If someone has some ideas...

Tryed to update the version without succès

Comment: Use StackOverflow for your SDLC related queries.

Comment: @varad_s Did you mix up "StackOverflow" and "ServerFault" in your comment ?

Comment: @cmbarbu actually I am trying to suggest that StackOverflow is better for programming and software development queries. ServerFault as you mentioned or even askubuntu can be more helpful for this type of questions. What do you think??

Comment: It would even be SuperUser actually @varad_s it it is not specific to Ubuntu. I added such a question there https://superuser.com/q/1804823/437878